# Where is this error message coming from?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This error message in Visual Studio Code 1.12.2 looks very important.

[image]

> *Transcription: Syntax error in selector "angular:animation" at position 8: Expected "declaration", "expression", "function",
>   "pattern" or "statement" but "a" ... [Tooltip hover text reads: Syntax
>   error in selector "angular:animation" at position 8: Expected
>   "declaration", "expression", "function", "pattern" or "statement" but
>   "a" found.]*

However, I have no idea what I can do about it.

1. Is an extension displaying it? If so, which could it be? I have about 30, and don't want to disable them all and individually enable each one.
2. Which file is this problem found in? It's not the file that I have open in my editor window.

The Problems window is blank.

I've checked all of the Output windows using the dropdown filter.

The Debug Console is blank.

How would I even begin to figure out the answer to my questions?

TO BE CLEAR: I don't need the error explained to me. My very first computer error was a syntax error way back in 1981. I have learned what those mean pretty well by now.

Comment: Would be best to include a screenshot or the error message

Comment: @Tushortz Are you not seeing the screenshot I included? That's not a banner ad, there. But I edited the question to include the transcription.

Comment: @Alex McBee do you have an `eslint` extension installed. Perhaps a latest upgrade is causing this issue. See https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/issues/456

Comment: @Tushortz I do. I'll check whether I have that version. I'll also open a new issue with both VSCode that they need to do better identifying the extension that creates these messages, and to the eslint chain that they need to identify the file and path of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this, Visual Studio Code has been updated to indicate the extension that displays the message:

[image]

It still doesn't help that the eslint module doesn't tell me *which* file is mentioned. The only messages in the Output window are not helpful, either, but that's another problem.

[image]